# Insertion sort giving array out of bounds errror

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error in the inner while loop of the insertion sort algorithm. This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class insetionSort {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int A[] = new int[100];
        int n;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            A[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }

        int i,j,v;

        for (i = 2;i < n-1;i++) {
            v = A[i];
            j = i;

            while((A[j-1]>v)&&(j>=1)) /*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1*/
            {
                A[j] = A[j-1];
                j--;
            }

            A[j] = v;
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            System.out.print(A[i]+'\t');
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error says it all - your variable `j` gets decremented to `-1`, which is not a valid array index. Lazy boolean expression evaluation is performed from left to right.

Comment: First problem : you add n elements but allocate an array of size 100. The user can crash your program very easily by inputting more than 100 items.

Answer (score 2):

The condition should be changed from

```
    while((A[j-1]>v)&&(j>=1))
```

to

```
    while((j>=1)&&(A[j-1]>v))
```

Otherwise, `A[j-1]` might get evaluated for `j==0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((A[j-1] > v) && (j >= 1)) {
    A[j] = A[j-1];
    j--;
}
```

Boolean expressions are evaluated from left to right. So when j becomes 0, `A[j - 1] > v` is evaluated first, before `j >= 1`. And it thus throws an exception.

Simply reading the message gives you a huge hint:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

So you know that the problem is that you're accessing an invalid index in an array, and that this invalid index is -1.

Use

```
while ((j >= 1) && (A[j-1] > v))
```